# Can object index be used as driver variable?

Tags: python, scripting, objects, drivers, groups

Is there any way to assign an order to multiple objects such that the index of each object can be used as a driving variable?

Comment: You can add custom properties to an object in the objects panel if thats what you want. Rearranging the object index `bpy.data.objects[index]` sounds like it wouldn't work easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bpy
bpy.types.Object.index = bpy.props.FloatProperty() #Create new property 'index'
obs = bpy.context.selected_objects
i=0
for ob in obs: #Object created last will be in the first iteration and so on
  ob.index=i   #Assign value for selected objects in reversed order of creation
  i+=1
```